# datetime2: Assuming missing inputs of minutes or seconds to be zero

Tags: datetime2

I would like to make the following document print output of `07:00 PM`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[calc,english]{datetime2}

\DTMnewtimestyle{ampm}{%
  % \DTMdisplaytime{<hh>}{<mm>}{<ss>}
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaytime}[3]{%
    \def\THEHOUR{##1}\def\THEAMPM{AM}% Assume AM
    \ifnum##1>12
      \edef\THEHOUR{\number\numexpr##1-12}% Correct for...
      \edef\THEAMPM{PM}%                    ...PM
    \fi
    \DTMtwodigits{\THEHOUR}% <hh>
    :%
    \DTMtwodigits{##2}% <mm>
    \space
    \THEAMPM% AM/PM
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\DTMsettimestyle{ampm}
\DTMtime{19}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `\DTMtime` requires an input in the form `hh:mm:ss` (but just one digit can be used in each part).

You can supply the missing parts with `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[calc,english]{datetime2}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xDTMtime}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{:}}m}{\xxDTMtime#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xxDTMtime}{mmm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \DTMtime{#1:00:00}%
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
      \DTMtime{#1:#2:00}%
    }{%
      \DTMtime{#1:#2:#3}%
    }%
  }%
}

\DTMnewtimestyle{ampm}{%
  % \DTMdisplaytime{<hh>}{<mm>}{<ss>}
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaytime}[3]{%
    \def\THEHOUR{##1}\def\THEAMPM{AM}% Assume AM
    \ifnum##1>12
      \edef\THEHOUR{\number\numexpr##1-12}% Correct for...
      \edef\THEAMPM{PM}%                    ...PM
    \fi
    \DTMtwodigits{\THEHOUR}% <hh>
    :%
    \DTMtwodigits{##2}% <mm>
    ~%
    \THEAMPM% AM/PM
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\DTMsettimestyle{ampm}

\xDTMtime{19}

\xDTMtime{19:15}

\xDTMtime{19:1:2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After experimenting, I think the output of `\xDTMtime{12}` should be `12:00 PM` instead of `12:00 AM`

Comment: @Diaa Reverse the test: `\ifnum##1<12 \else`

Comment: How can I store the time in a macro? For instance, I need to save the time `19:1:2` in `\mytime` then use it later `\xDTMtime{\mytime}`. I tried `\newcommand{\mytime}{19:1:2}` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Diaa `\expandafter\xDTMtime\expandafter{\mytime}`